# ' builtin_function_or_method ' , How to overcome this Error

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, facial-identification

```
Expressions={0:"Angry",1:"Disgust",2:"Fear",3:"Happy",4:"Sad",5:"Surprise",6:"Neutral"}
from keras.utils import to_categorical 
labels = to_categorical(labels,len(Expressions))
images = np.array([np.fromstring(pixel, dtype=int,sep=" ")for pixel in pixels])
images = images/255.00
images = images.reshape(images.reshape[0],48,48,1).astype('float32')
```

I'm getting this error while converting the grayscale image into 48x48, so anyone can give me a good response.

getting this error in the code;

```
  1 images = np.array([np.fromstring(pixel, dtype=int, sep=" ")for pixel in pixels])
  2 images = images/255.00
----> 3 images = images.reshape(images.reshape[0],48,48,1).astype('float32')

TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

[image]

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: As you can see from the outermost call, `reshape is a function`.

Answer (score 1):

`reshape` is a function. You have to change it to:

```
images = images.reshape(images.shape[0],48,48,1).astype('float32')
```

the first arg is `images.shape[0]` instead of `images.reshape[0]`

Comment: Yes, but now you get another error...That`s because you try to reshape an array of size 2747 to (2747, 48, 48, 1)...

Comment: How can I solved it, I'm learning this on my own and got this error.